# Add parameters to post request with Rest-client rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, rest-client

I need to make a Post request using Rest-Client in my rails backend. I can successfully do it by the following: `rv = RestClient.post URL, id.to_json, :content_type => 'application/json'`

I need to add a tag parameter but can't make it work. I've tried different combinations of the following: `rv = RestClient.post URL, {:params => {:tag => 'TAG'}}, id.to_json, :content_type => 'application/json'` and receive errors about syntax (wrong number of arguments). The params would go on the url, the id.to_json would be part of the body. I can't find documentation that talks about this specific use case.

Comment: please add code of your Controller which you send post to and your routes.rb file

Comment: This would be an external request. There is no problem with the service, its getting the syntax properly set up for the call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use to_query to convert a hash into a HTTP query string like so:

```
url_params = {:tag => "TAG"}.to_query
=> "tag=TAG"
```

Then just use that to construct your entire URL:

```
rv = RestClient.post "#{URL}?#{url_params}", id.to_json, :content_type => 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 1):

there is another way to add url parameters to the request, it is notable that you have not sent the `post` parameters to `RestClient` in the correct order, which is `url , payload, headers`. and the headers can include any other tag, like `:params`.

> rv = RestClient.post(URL, id.to_json, {:params => {:tag => 'TAG'},
>   :content_type => 'application/json' })